# Regex grab a substring from a string

Tags: regex, bash

Anyone familiar with how to use regex grab the following expression:

```
Random1 `json:"random1"`
Random2 `json:"random2"`
Random3 `json:"random3"`
```

desired output:

```sh
random1
random2
random3
```

What I have tried so far:

Try one:

```
grep -o '(\".*?\")' example1.file
```

Try two:

```
grep -o '\"*\"' example1.file
```

returned nothing

This returns everything but just want the substring:

Attempt 3

```
grep -E "\"(.*)\"" example1.file
```

Expected output:

```
random1
random2
random3
```

Comment: `awk -F\" '{print $2}' file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/^.*"(.*)"`$|.*/\1/g' example1.file
```

This (the `|.*` part) also clears lines without a match. Which then can be easily filtered out with `... | grep .`

Comment: Worked on Mac fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `-P` with lookarounds, so that the quotes won't be included in the match.

```
grep -o -P '(?<").*(?=")' example1.file
```

This requires GNU `grep` to get the `-P` option for PCRE.

Comment: This works well on linux

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep and a Perl-compatible regular expression:

```
grep -Po '(?<=").*(?=")' file
```

Output:

```
random1
random2
random3
```

Comment: This works will on linux.  For mac users make sure gnu grep with -P